# How to display date in new table

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I apologize for the weird title, I'm new and I don't quite know the term for my question.
I made a stock prediction program following a tutorial and this is what it displays right now. How do I get the dates to display alongside their respective prices? In the .csv file, the column showing dates is labeled 'Date'.

[image]

This is the code that creates this table

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test.flatten(), 'Predicted': predicted.flatten()})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your question you just want to add a new column to your data frame. Just add a new column to your `dframe` from your `csv` `data`.

```
dframe["newcolumnfordate"]=data["Date"]
```

Comment: It worked, thanks!! My csv file also has about 2000 rows. But the code only shows 500 rows at maximum. Is this a limit set by sklearn or is there a way to show all 2000 rows?

Comment: try:
`pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)`
or just save it as csv and check whether the problem is about the your IDE or not::
`dframe.to_csv("dframe.csv",index=False)`